# WIX - uninstall is not working when triggered from Apps & Features in Windows 10

Tags: wix, windows-10

I am using WiX v3.11 in my application. When I try to uninstall my application(let it be **Abc**) using **Apps & Features** in **32-bit** Windows 10 system, then it displays the following error:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcETq.png)

The error message is **"C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" Element not found**.

On clicking **OK**, the uninstall cancels but the explorer remains closed.
However, when I uninstall the same application using **Control Panel**, it works fine.

And In a **64-bit** Windows 10 machine, un-installation is happening from **Apps & Features** but with the following results:

1. Account details from **%localappdata%** is not removed. Hence  user name field is getting populated by default  with the previous logged in user details after re-installing **Abc**. User can not delete the **Abc**'s folder without restarting explorer.
2. **Abc**'s Process is still running as a background thread in Task manager after uninstalling **Abc** .

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, try using the CloseApplication element in your Install Execute Sequence. http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/closeapplication.html